# Drupal 7 contexual filter display block based on node reference

Tags: views, entities

I have been going around in circles with this for a few hours now... Time to ask for help!!

I have two Content Types:

1: Book

2: Reader

The `Book` Content Type has a `node reference` field which is a select list of readers create with the `Reader` Content Type.

This is all set up and working fine.

Now the issue with my views:

I have a view with is a block containing the `Reader` fields. What I want to do is have it when the `Book` node is loaded my block shows underneath with the referenced `reader` details. Also if no reader is referenced then no block shows up.

I have spent some time in `Relationship` and `Contextual Filters` but can't get it to work.

The book URL is formatted like this:

books/[book-title]

I tired using 'raw value from url' in `Contextual Filters` as setting it to the 2nd argument but that didn't work either.

If anyone can help me out here I would be very much appreciative.

Thanks
C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I would do if I am understanding this correctly:

Create a new view block

1.) Create a view with Filter critera:  **Content type is book**
2.) Then I would create a Relationship to: **Content Reader**
3.) Add all the fields and add a relationship to the Reader content type (whatever you want displayed from the reader content)
4.) Add a contextual filer with: **Content NID**, where it says WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE click on the **Provide default value** radio and select **Content ID from URL**
5.)  Add that block to the story display page wherever needed

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the default drupal display for the book.. I just need the reader info below it. are you sure is no way to do it this way?

Comment: Let me try to understand this.  So you have a book node and trying to use the default display page to display the book information, then you want to display the reader information on the book node underneath the book display?  And that you need to know this according to the book title?

Comment: yes.. but the book title was just something I tried... clearly not right... The book has the Node Reference field that allows you to select the reader. What ever reader is selected from that list while creating the book node is displayed in a block underneath the book. Hope that makes more sence.

Comment: Read my new solution and see if that is what you are trying to do

Comment: Thanks... all seemed to be working perfect up to a point... before I did point 4 I had two readers showing which is exactly what I expect to see as I have 12 books but only two of them have referenced readers. BUT, as soon as I added the contextual filter nothing showed up. I then added the Book URL to the `Preview with contextual filters:` input and hit `Update Preview`.. still nothing. This is the URL of the one of the Book nodes: `domain.com/books/the-is-my-test-book`. `This is my first book` is the title of the book. ideas?

Comment: Attempt to add the block to the book page and see if it displays. Is this site on a dev site somewhere or local?

Comment: should the contextual filter use the Relationship?

Comment: No it should because you will want to get the NID from the book and not the reader.  Did you try to enter the url in the filter?  You can also just try to put the NID of the book and it should display.  But I would also attempt to put the block on the page to see what happens there?

Comment: OK... that works on the actual page. YAY!!! Thanks so much. I can't express my appreciation enough.

Comment: Not a problem that is a tricky one sometimes!!